# The 'configuration' element is not declared in Visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015

I have some problem about my App visual Studio, especially in my Xamarin, 
I wanna ask why everytime I compile, this message always come?

`The 'configuration' element is not declared.App4.Android`

this is my Source code,

can anybody help me?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`

    <configuration>            
    <runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.29.0" newVersion="4.2.29.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>`
```